# Does the “post/redirect/get" pattern create security problems?

Tags: e-commerce

My understanding of Post-Redirect-Get so far is not very deep.  I've used it a couple of times now.  What I notice, though, is that when I use it, I am sending a rather private token of some sort to the last page in the GET request. It is a token that allows the server to respond with information about the just-completed transaction.  The way I'm using it is:

```
[Page 1        ]        [Page 2       ]         [Page 3                     ]
[Form to submit] =====> [Processes Trx] ======> [Has querystring parameter  ]
[              ]  POST  [             ]  REDIR  [that gets a plot of the Trx]
```

So the Querystring sent to Page 3 has info that causes the server to plot information about the transaction.  Worse, the Querystring is shown out in the open in a browser.  It seems someone can pretty easily get my Querystring parameters and then go look at my transaction at any later time.

- Is my understanding of the exposure correct?  Does SSL hide it from all?
- Do you implement it differently than I'm doing?
- Is there perhaps a P-R-"P" pattern that *posts* to Page 3, so at least the information about accessing the transaction is not in full view?  (We would not want Page 3 to have a side effect, just get info, but I'm trying not to expose a private token.)
- Does that help at all, or is it just as insecure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems someone can pretty easily get my Querystring parameters and then go look at my transaction at any later time.

Maybe it is like this, maybe not. The actual implementation is not known. But one can prevent the behavior you describe by

- Having a short expiration on the string, so it can only be used within the very short time the redirect is expected to be processed by the client. This way it cannot be used later.
- Clearing the validity of the string after first use (i.e. after successful redirect) so it cannot be used again.
- Binding the string to the current session of the client, i.e. session cookie or similar, so that it cannot be used without also having access to the session information.

It should also be **used with TLS** so that the attacker cannot just capture the request and use it before the client does, since the request contains the string and also the session information. But this is actually **not only true for this kind of pattern but for all kind of actions which include the session information** - these could otherwise be simply hijacked and changed to cause different things.

Comment: Thank you for these ideas, Steffen.  I could see either of the first two being usable in some situations.  But the third idea sounds possibly the best.  I'm not very knowledgeable as to how to use session info, so I'm not fully understanding how you would do that.  Would you pass the "access-the-confirmation-of-this-trx" token as a session variable, or session-only cookie?  Can you help me with a little more explicit description of that?  Or maybe point me to an article, if you know of one.

Comment: @MarkGoldfain: To detail the idea a bit more: for example the ID could by some random string + expiration time, followed by a HMAC over this with the session id used as secret. To verify the HMAC the current session id from the cookie will be used - if none is send or not the proper one the verification will fail and thus access will be rejected.